# Flaw in Proof that Closure of Intersection is Intersection of Closure

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $A,B$ be two subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I know it's not true that $\overline{A\cap B}=\overline{A}\cap\overline{B},$ but where's my flaw here?

$$\begin{align*}x\in\overline{A\cap B}&\iff \forall\varepsilon\gt0 \ B_\varepsilon(x)\cap(A\cap B)\neq\emptyset\\ &\iff \forall\varepsilon\gt0 \ B_\varepsilon(x)\cap A\neq\emptyset\text{ and }\forall\varepsilon\gt0 \ B_\varepsilon(x)\cap B\neq\emptyset\\&\iff x\in\overline{A}\text{ and } x\in\overline{B} \\ &\iff x\in\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}.\end{align*} $$

In line $2$ I'm using the fact that $X\cap Y\cap Z=(X\cap Y)\cap (X\cap Z).$

Comment: You can have $A\cap C\neq\varnothing$ and $B\cap C\neq\varnothing$ and yet $(A\cap B)\cap C=\varnothing$, so the implication isn't bidirectional in your second line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that $\forall \epsilon > 0 B_\epsilon(x) \cap A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ is *not* equivalent to $\forall \epsilon > 0 (B_\epsilon(x) \cap A \neq \emptyset \land B_\epsilon(x) \cap B \neq \emptyset)$.

Take $A = (0, 1)$, $B = (1, 2)$, $x = 1$ to see this.